# Plotting Magnitude and Phase of Fourier Transform

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot the magnitude and phase representation of a fourier transform.

Here is what I have so far:

```
syms t w
y(t) = 2*cos(2000*pi*t)*cos(2*pi*(10^6)*t);
x(w) = fourier(y);
h = abs(x);
a = angle(x)
figure, fplot(h)
figure, fplot(a)
```

But when I plot I just get two straight lines at 0. I understand that the fourier transform returns dirac delta functions. Is there anyway I can plot these functions in matlab?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar example that explicitly defines the vector `t`:

```
t = linspace(0,1,82);
y = 2*cos(2000*pi*t).*cos(2*pi*(10^6)*t);
x = fft(y);
h = abs(x);
a = angle(x);

figure, plot(t, x)
figure, plot(t, a)
```

I have a hunch that your `t` vector is incremented in a manner that only produces values of "some-integer" multiplied by `pi`. This will result in values of `-1` and `1` being returned from the `cos` function evaluated in radians.

The code above produces the following:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is great! One question though, shouldn't the horizontal axis span over a certain number of frequencies, as opposed to 0-1? Maybe I'm not understanding this correctly

Comment: Yes it is, my apologies it's been a few years since I've worked with Fourier transforms. You can follow the docs here, which work through a similar example and convert from time to frequency: https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/angle.html.